# Error in QSqlTableModel inherited table

Tags: c++, qt4

I have this class that inherits from QSqlTableModel and it brokes after calling the submitAll() slot, after calling insertPoint some times. Here is the code.

Thanks for the help.

Regards.

```
#ifndef VWLANDMARKTABLEMODEL_H
#define VWLANDMARKTABLEMODEL_H

#include <QSqlTableModel>

class GraphicsPointLandmarkItem;

class VWLandmarkTableModel : public QSqlTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum Column {
        IdColumn=0,
        IdImageColumn=1,
        UsernameColumn=2,
        NameColumn=3,
        DefinitionColumn=4
    };

    VWLandmarkTableModel(QObject *parent=0);

    int idImage() const { return m_idImage; }
    QString username() const { return m_username; }
    void setIdImage(int idImage);
    void setUsername(const QString &username);
    virtual bool select();
    bool insertPoint(GraphicsPointLandmarkItem *item);
signals:
protected:
    virtual void setFilter(const QString &filter) 
        { QSqlTableModel::setFilter(filter); }
    virtual bool insertRowIntoTable(const QSqlRecord &values);
protected slots:
    void setDefaults(int row, QSqlRecord &r);
private:
    QString m_username;
    int m_idImage;
};

#endif // VWLANDMARKTABLEMODEL_H


#include "vwlandmarktablemodel.h"

#include <QtGui>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtCore>

#include "graphicspointlandmarkitem.h"

VWLandmarkTableModel::VWLandmarkTableModel(QObject *parent)
    : QSqlTableModel(parent)
{ 
    setTable("vwLandmark");
    setEditStrategy(OnManualSubmit);

    connect(this, SIGNAL(primeInsert(int,QSqlRecord&)), 
        SLOT(setDefaults(int,QSqlRecord&)));
}

void VWLandmarkTableModel::setIdImage(int idImage)
{ m_idImage=idImage; }

void VWLandmarkTableModel::setUsername(const QString &username)
{ m_username=username; }

bool VWLandmarkTableModel::select()
{
    Q_ASSERT(!username().isEmpty());

    QString stmt="IdImage = %1 AND Username = '%2'";

    setFilter(stmt.arg(idImage()).arg(username()));
    return QSqlTableModel::select();
}

bool VWLandmarkTableModel::insertPoint(GraphicsPointLandmarkItem *item)
{
    QString text;
    QTextStream out(&text);
    int row=rowCount();
    bool ok;

    ok=insertRow(row); Q_ASSERT(ok);

    QModelIndex idx=index(row, DefinitionColumn);

    out<<*item;
    ok=setData(idx, text); 
    Q_ASSERT(ok);
    idx=index(row, NameColumn);
    ok=setData(idx, tr("New point landmark"));
    Q_ASSERT(ok);
    return ok;
}

bool VWLandmarkTableModel::insertRowIntoTable(const QSqlRecord &values)
{
    QString sql="EXEC InsertLandmark :IdImage,:Definition";
    QSqlQuery q;
    bool ok;

    ok=q.prepare(sql); Q_ASSERT(ok);
    q.bindValue(":IdImage", values.value("IdImage"));
    q.bindValue(":Definition", values.value("Definition"));
    q.setForwardOnly(true);
    if(!q.exec()) {
        setLastError(q.lastError());
        return false;
    }
    qDebug()<<"hola mundo";
    return true;
}

void VWLandmarkTableModel::setDefaults(int row, QSqlRecord &r)
{
    r.setValue("IdImage", idImage());
    r.setValue("Name", "Unnamed landmark");
    r.setValue("Username", username());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my custom select. Calling setFilter() causes a infinite calling loop